# Debian 6 - wget failed: Connection timed out from specific URL

Tags: proxy, debian, wget, iptables

I try to download from a specific url using the command `wget` on the server Debian 6 as follows:

```
# wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz
```

the result:

```
--2016-05-25 16: 39: 15-- http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.ruby-lang.org ... 221.186.184.75
Connecting to ftp.ruby-lang.org | 221.186.184.75 |: 80 ... failed: Connection timed out.
```

however, if I access the url using the browser, it can be accessed with a normal ...
I know why I do not use alternative via the browser earlier.
I just want to understand the intent of the problem, which is a new thing for me ..

so, why did this happen? iptables influence or proxy or other things I really do not understand.
someone might help in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Purely a connectivity issue.  I bet you have the network configured in another way in your browser, i can `wget` that file (from that same IP) without issues from servers in London (UK), Dublin and New York (well, New Jersey).  My `wget` does the transfer through port 80 (and over HTTP), just like yours is trying.  That `ftp` in the hostname is misleading, although `wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz` works as well.

Comment: @grochmal thank for your repply. but, I still don't understand about this issue,, I have tried to check connectivity, ping some url like google.com, yahoo.com and ping default gateway is OK. I'm still confused and should learn a lot :-)